# is there any possible way to display message in both javascript and server side code in one asp button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My label and button:

```
<h1 id="display"></h1>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="display" 
     Onclientclick="return show()" onclick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function show() {
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                                         "iam client side code";
   return true;
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "iam server side code";
}
```

my problem is that when I click on the button click event, client side code calls and next server side code is calling. when server side code calls page refreshes the client side message disappears .How do I display both messages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you coded a server side button it'll cause a postback to the server. So in two ways you can handle this situation.

***First***, what you have already tried is handling the message display on client side only. What you need to do is change the server side button into a simple `input` element.

**Second**, approach would be to use AjaxExtension `<asp:UpdatePanel></asp:UpdatePanel>` that will only send the control you want to the server side and won't cause full page reload rather a partial postback.

***Second Approach Code :*** Update your code as follows,

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <h1 id="display"></h1>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="display" 
             Onclientclick="return show()" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>  
</div>
```

Comment: In first scenario,if I would give that server side button as simple "input" element it acts like a html button.How button click event fires on server side,and your second approach works absolutely fine :)

Comment: I already mentioned `handling the message display on client side only`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call javascript from button post back also.
you can follow this example

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Practise.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show() {
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =  "iam client side code";
            return true;
        }
        </script> </head> <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1 id="display"></h1>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="display"   onclick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </form> </body> </html>
```

Server side code is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "iam server side code";

            StringBuilder runscript = new StringBuilder();
            runscript.AppendLine("show();");

            ClientScriptManager manager = Page.ClientScript;
            manager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "any", runscript.ToString(), true);
        }
```